# Tags tab doesn't show up in my self-installed Team Foundation Server (TFS) 2017

Tags: git, tfs, git-tag

I installed TFS 2017 on my server. I cannot use the online service for some reasons! Everything works fine except the Tags tab doesn't show up as in the picture below:

[image: Tags tab not showing up]

I have some tags available in my repository as in the picture below:

[image]

I also push the tags to TFS

[image]

I have checked out some articles, I could see the tags tab in all of them but why it doesn't show up on my TFS.

Some articles I have read:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/06/14/view-tags-for-git-repositories/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/how-to/git-tags?tabs=vsts-tfs-web-portal

Comment: Did you push the tags to the remote?

Comment: I had done that.

Answer (score 2):

That's the expected behavior.

**Tags** tab is not supported on TFS 2017. It's only supported on TFS 2018 and VSTS (Visual Studio Team Services).

In TFS 2017, you can see the tags in Commit detail page (`History --> Commits`).

You can refer to [Working with Git tags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/how-to/git-tags?tabs=vsts-tfs-web-portal#view-tag-history) for more information about the Git Tags.

Comment: @Quan Have you checked that I mentioned in above answer. Just note that Tags tab is not supported on TFS 2017. If you want to use that tab, just try upgrading toTFS 2018 or migrating to VSTS